# Hybris - Table cxabstractaction doesn't exist

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm doing system update from hac. But I'm getting following error in the console. I looked in the *-items.xml for **cxabstractaction** itemtype, but couldn't find it. I am using SAP Hybris 1808 version with mysql 8.x version.

```
 [java] Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hybrisD2C.cxabstractaction' doesn't exist
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.StatementWithJDBCInterceptor.lambda$2(StatementWithJDBCInterceptor.java:53)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.passThrough(SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.java:101)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.get(SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.java:59)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.JDBCInterceptor.get(JDBCInterceptor.java:69)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.StatementWithJDBCInterceptor.executeQuery(StatementWithJDBCInterceptor.java:53)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:161)
     [java]     at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.determineAutoIncrementFromResultSetMetaData(JdbcModelReader.java:1064)
     [java]     at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.mysql.MySqlModelReader.readTable(MySqlModelReader.java:67)
     [java]     at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.readTables(JdbcModelReader.java:516)
     [java]     at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.getDatabase(JdbcModelReader.java:472)
     [java]     at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.JdbcModelReader.getDatabase(JdbcModelReader.java:432)
     [java]     at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.PlatformImplBase.readModelFromDatabase(PlatformImplBase.java:1884)
     [java]     ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of `personalizationservices` extension. Check the `hybris/bin/modules/personalization/personalizationservices/resources/personalizationservices-items.xml` file.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't see **personalizationservices** extension in workspace. I also checked Hybris home, but don't see "modules" directory within bin directory.

Comment: @BNR The modules is in the newer versions of Hybris. What version are you using? I'm not sure if th older versions have the personalizationservices extension. Try to add personalizationservices to your localextensions.xml and see if "ant all" will build it.

Comment: @geffchang - I am using 1808 version.